# How to Know a Word Table's Index Number?

Tags: indexing, vbscript, ms-word

I have this large Word doc with 100 tables. However, I only need to use 3 tables for a VB script, example:

```
Set tbl = wdDoc.Tables(1)
```

Where this refers to the first table in the Word doc. However, the 3 tables are in the middle of the document. How may I know their "index number" instead of manually checking if they are the nth table in the document?

Comment: Are you really using VB.Net? That is what you tagged the question with, but the text suggests that you are using VBScript or VBA (Visual Basic for Applications). Those are all different languages.

Comment: I apologize. I thought VB was referring to Visual Basic. My intention was to tag it under Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0):

I assign names to the `Title` property of tables I need to identify. Then I loop through all the tables in the document and pick out the one with the `Title` I want.

Comment: Hi Variatus. Sorry, do you have a sample code on how to do this? Or the steps? I'm sorry, I am clueless